Spring webclient add custom message in log
Newbie to webclient/Flux .I have been trying to log the webclient request/response headers and body . With netty wiretap I am able to print the headers and body. But however I would want to have a custom message that is readable from some of the internal tools we have . I would like the log to have a custom prefix before logging like headers, body etc.
Headers : ****
Body : ******
Tried adding a custom filter

     * public ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest() { return
     * ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor((final ClientRequest request) -> {
     * 
     * final String headers = getHeaders(request);
     * log.info("======request ======"); 
                
     * log.info("Headers     : " + headers); 
     * }
     * 
     * log.info("=====request end======"); return Mono.just(request); }); }
     */

However I am unable to get the body content.
Is there an efficient way to log body and the headers with custom messages.
Thanks
Is there an efficient way to log body and the headers with custom messages.

Consider using https://github.com/zalando/logbook
It allows logging request and response
Example code:
final Logbook logbook = Logbook.create();
StepVerifier.create(
                WebClient.builder()
                        .filter(new LogbookExchangeFilterFunction(logbook))
                        .build()
                        .post()
                        .uri(uri -> uri
                                        .scheme("http")
                                        .host("localhost")
                                        .port(8080)
                                        .pathSegment("test")
                                        .build()
                        )
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .bodyValue("{}")
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        )
        .expectNextCount(1)
        .verifyComplete();
}

Useful links:
https://github.com/zalando/logbook/issues/1485
https://github.com/zalando/logbook/issues/140
